# Obtaining Session-data from database table in MVC Core

Tags: session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my MVC Core application I'm using sessions to track logins. This works great, but is an issue when my web application goes idle/restarts, as the sessions clears and all users gets logged out. I've modified my application to store the session data in a database caching-table, through calling and setting `services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options)` & `services.AddSession(options)` in the Startup `ConfigureServices` method, as well as calling `app.UseSession()` in the `Configure` method.

I seem to have done everything correctly; when a new client for the first time sets a session value it's saved in the caching-table, and when `Sesion.Get` is called the session `ExpiresAtTime` table-value updates.

So, considering that the session data is saved to the table, why is it not being grabbed on restarts? It isn't a cookie issue, the cookie expiration value is set to 10 years, and the session idle timeout value is set to 2 weeks. It seems like the Session data is just being handled through IIS memory, yet is being saved to my caching db-table, which I find very weird.

Comment: From your description, everything sounds correct, but it would be helpful to see the actual code from `Startup.cs`. It's possible there's a mistake there you're not noticing and didn't describe in your question as a result.

Comment: I've looked over it multiple times, scanning for errors and trying different options, the code should be correct but you're right, new eyes doesn't hurt https://pastebin.com/bY1gtDG5

Comment: Try moving all your distributed cache / session config before `services.AddMvc()`. Order often matters on this and that's where it's usually seen going.

Comment: I've tried that in the past, tried now again with different orders but made no difference; Session data is still not getting grabbed on restarts. Been fiddling with this problem on and off for many weeks now, tried all guides and ideas I've come across and thought of without any solution. Might just be an issue with MVC Core.